# How to Install PgBouncer as a software if possible

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, quarkus, pgbouncer

I want to use Pgbouncer on my windows machine. Is there any way so that I can download it as a software and simply provide it's URL in place of my DB url in Quarkus and spring boot application or how can I use it on my windows machine?

I need all the steps that I need to follow, can someone help me here?

Comment: You would have to build  it per [Windows build](https://www.pgbouncer.org/install.html#building-on-windows), followed by [Running on Windows](https://www.pgbouncer.org/install.html#running-on-windows).